# Replace selected text from Action Extension

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am working on Action Extension. Ideally I want be able to:

1. In Safari select text from any text field
2. Tap **Share** from edit options
3. Perform text generation in extension
4. Tap **Done** button

Selected text should be replaced with the text generated in extension but it's not.

```
@IBAction func done() {

    var result = extensionContext!.inputItems

    if let currentText = outputLabel.text {
        if currentText.isEmpty == false {
            viewModel.currentText = currentText
            viewModel.saveCurrentText()

            let extensionItem = NSExtensionItem()
            extensionItem.attachments = [NSItemProvider(item: currentText as NSString, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeText as String)]
            result = [extensionItem]
        }
    }

    extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: result, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: i think the safari Share function is not a 'replace text' function.

Comment: it seems only a one way

Comment: Apple Activity Sheet can be called from many places including Safari and any place where you can select text. We as developers have choice to put Share and Action activities there. Share activities go on the top, and actions - bottom. If sandbox doesn't allow to modify activity patents app data, how 1Password app extension can fill your username and password? And if this is not possible, why API gives us an option to return something at all?